# Automatic documentation/contract generation for Pub/Sub RabbitMQ

Tags: rest, rabbitmq, amqp, code-contracts, swagger-2.0

In the REST world, we have something like a Swagger Specification, which fully describes the contract over a REST interface boundary (between client and server). Those Swagger specifications can be used to auto-generate REST clients, but also to automatically generate documentation for your REST API consumers. These Swagger Specification, moreover, are also a valuable asset w.r.t. CI and versioning of your API.

I was wondering if a similar solution exists in the asynchronous Publish Subscribe world: let's say a typical AMQP Consumer/Producer on RabbitMQ....

Best regards,

Bart

Answer (score 3):

FYI, currently looking into following solutions:

- https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/spec.html
- https://github.com/hopped/rabbitmq-avro

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered this, and it is promising:
https://www.asyncapi.com/